# Merging array if have same key with previous element

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge

I have associative array like this:

```
[
    ['one' => 'data 1'],
    ['two' => 'data 2'],
    ['two' => 'data 3'],
    ['three' => 'data 4'],
    ['two' => 'data 5'],
    ['two' => 'data 6'],
    ['two' => 'data 7'],
    ['four' => 'data 8'],
]
```

and I want to join them like this:

```
[
    ['one' => 'data 1'],
    ['two' => ['data 2', 'data 3'] ],
    ['three' => 'data 4'],
    ['two' => ['data 5', 'data 6', 'data 7'] ],
    ['four' => 'data 8'],
]
```

I've tried array_map and etc. but I can't get result like I want. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

my current code like this:

```
$valBefore = null;
$out = [];
foreach($array as $k => $subarray) {
   foreach($subarray as $kk => $vv) {
      if ($valBefore == $kk) {
         $temp = $out[$k-1][$kk];
         $out[$k-1][$kk] = [ $temp, $vv ];
         unset($out[$k]);
      }
      $valBefore = $kk;
   }
   $out[] = $subarray;
}
```

The output like this:

```
[
   { "one": "data 1" },
   { "two": [ "data 2", "data 3" ] },
   { "two": "data 3" },
   { "three": "data 4", },
   { "two": [ "data 5", "data 6" ] },
   { "two": [ "data 6", "data 7" ] },
   { "two": "data 7" },
   { "four": "data 8" }
]
```

(that `unset()` still not working) This is my best code for now and I still try to make it fit to the output that I want.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tired (that didn't work)?

Comment: @KoalaYeung sorry I already delete it for trying another method (still not working), ill edit with my current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the result you desire, you can use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php). In the callback you compare the key of the current element with the key of the last element in the accumulator. If they're the same, you push a new value to that element, otherwise you push a new element into the accumulator:

```
$result = array_reduce($array, function ($c, $a) {
    $len = count($c);
    $key = key($a);
    if ($key == key($c[$len-1] ?? [])) {
        if (is_array($c[$len-1][$key])) {
            $c[$len-1][$key][]= $a[$key];
        }
        else {
            $c[$len-1][$key] = array($c[$len-1][$key], $a[$key]);
        }
    }
    else {
        $c[] = $a;
    }
    return $c;
}, []);

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [one] => data 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [two] => Array
                (
                    [0] => data 2
                    [1] => data 3
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [three] => data 4
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [two] => Array
                (
                    [0] => data 5
                    [1] => data 6
                    [2] => data 7
                )
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [four] => data 8
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/PpbXC)